# Using def in python

Tags: python

I am trying to define a function in python but I am getting an error, here is the code,

```
def func greet_user():
"""Display a simple greeting."""
    print("Hello!")
    greet_user()
```

Then I get the error, "invalid syntax" 
.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `def func` is not valid; just write `def`. And strings are delimited with either one quote character, or three - you can't use two.

Comment: You should probably read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) first.

Comment: Post the entire message including the stack trace. It shows us the line with the failure.

Comment: It just said Syntax invalid" @tdelany But I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you fix indentation you need to wrap ""display a simple greeting"" in triple quotes.
Then change `def func greet_user():` to `def greet_user():`

Answer (score 2):

Python enforces strict indentation, all the content of a python function, including the comments, needs to be equally indented.
To fix your case, you should:

1) remove "func" from 'def func greet_user():',

2) tab the docstrings,

3) untab when you call the function outside of the function.

Also docstrings needs three quotation marks `"""string"""` not `""string ""`

Comment: It still says invalid syntax.

Comment: The string needs """ not "" to be valid

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def greet_user():
    print("""Display a simple greeting.""")
    print("Hello!")

greet_user()
```

Output:

**Display a simple greeting.**

**Hello!**

Comment: 'Display a simple greeting' was probably a docstring, not part of the intended output. I'd suggest not printing it, as it changes the author's intent.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `func` and move `greet_user()` out of the function (unindent)

```py
def greet_user(): #display a simple greeting
    print("Hello!")

greet_user() #prints 'Hello!'
```